# Using CUDA math functions in a __global__ function - Nsight Eclipse Edition

Tags: cuda

I am trying to use a math function (pow) in a __global__ function but I get this error :

```
 calling a __host__ function("std::pow<float, double> ") from a __global__ function is not allowed
```

and I tried to check the "Make use of fast math library" check box under project properties -> build -> settings -> Tool Settings -> optimization and no luck.

I checked the types inside the pow function and both are floats, and I've also included these header files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "utils.h"
```

also no using namespace std

any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to read the error message more carefully. The key piece of information is

```
std::pow<float, double>
```

Note: `<float,double>`. You have a call to `pow` with a double precision and a single precision argument. The CUDA math library is implemented by template overloading of selected standard library functions, but the arguments you have don't have a matching overload. Fix you code to have either all double precision or all single precision arguments, and the error will disappear.

Comment: Supported variants of pow() are: pow(float,float), pow(float,int), pow(double,double), pow(double,int). Note that pow() is quite slow, in many cases one of the following functions, which are special cases of exponentiation, can give better performance (where applicable, of course): exp, exp2, exp10, expm1, sqrt, rsqrt, cbrt, rcbrt. For squaring or cubing, write x*x, x*x*x. See the Best Practices Guide.