# Using CUDA math functions in a __global__ function in caffe

Tags: cuda, caffe

For some reason,I have to change the source code of caffe. Here is the modified code.

headfile

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cfloat>
#include <vector>
#include "caffe/layer.hpp"
#include "caffe/util/math_functions.hpp"
#include "caffe/vision_layers.hpp"
```

modified code

```
template <typename Dtype>
__global__ void LPPoolForward(const int nthreads,
const Dtype* const bottom_data, const int num, const int channels,
const int height, const int width, const int pooled_height,
const int pooled_width, const int kernel_h, const int kernel_w,
const int stride_h, const int stride_w, const int pad_h, const int pad_w,float p,
Dtype* const top_data) {
CUDA_KERNEL_LOOP(index, nthreads) {
const int pw = index % pooled_width;
const int ph = (index / pooled_width) % pooled_height;
const int c = (index / pooled_width / pooled_height) % channels;
const int n = index / pooled_width / pooled_height / channels;
int hstart = ph * stride_h - pad_h;
int wstart = pw * stride_w - pad_w;
int hend = min(hstart + kernel_h, height + pad_h);
int wend = min(wstart + kernel_w, width + pad_w);
hstart = max(hstart, 0);
wstart = max(wstart, 0);
hend = min(hend, height);
wend = min(wend, width);
Dtype lp = 0;
double p1=p;
const Dtype* const bottom_slice =bottom_data + (n * channels + c)*height* width;
for (int h = hstart; h < hend; ++h) {
  for (int w = wstart; w < wend; ++w) {

    lp += pow(bottom_slice[h * width + w],p1);
    lp += pow(bottom_slice[h * width + w],p);

  }
}
     top_data[index] = pow(lp,1/p1);
}
}
}
```

[Using CUDA math functions in a __global__ function - Nsight Eclipse Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760893/using-cuda-math-functions-in-a-global-function-nsight-eclipse-edition)
From that,I know pow() must have either all double precision or all single precision arguments.
The problem is that when I use `p1(double),lp += pow(bottom_slice[h * width + w],p1)`,this happened

> calling a __host__ function("std::pow< float, double> ") from a __global__ function is not allowed

and when I use `p(float),lp += pow(bottom_slice[h * width + w],p)`this happened

> error: calling a __host__ function("std::pow< double, float> ") from a __global__ function("caffe::LPPoolForward ") is not allowed

Why when I changed the precision of the second parameter of pow,the first also changed? I am not very familiar with caffe, so any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Is the kernel you are modifying templated? You haven't provided enough information for someone else to be able to answer your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you have shown some more code, the reason is obvious. The kernel in question is a template, meaning that the code can be instantiated for *both* single and double precision types. By fixing the code for single precision, you break it for double precision. And vice versa.

The solution is to make the intermediate variables you declare `Dtype`. Then, depending on the type the kernel is instantiated with, the arguments will always match and there will be no problems with `pow` during compilation.

Comment: To add background: The immediate reason for the errors seen is that CUDA [1] uses the host toolchain's `math.h` and [2] provides implementations of `pow(float,float)`, `pow(double,double)`, `pow(float,int)`, and `pow(double,int)` for device code. So the compiler finds no implementation for device code of `pow(float,double)` and `pow(double, float)`, but it apparently does find prototypes for host-side versions of these functions. However, host functions cannot be called from device code, resulting in the errors shown in the question.